# Angular2: successful login and logout get redirected to localhost:3000/#

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I use PathLocationStrategy with Angular2 rc.4 (router 3.0.0-beta.2).

I'm runing into weird problem with touter redirecting.

**Case 1:** first clear browser history/cached file

After successful login from `localhost:3000/login`, router redirects to `localhost:3000`, which is as expected.

After logout, router first redirects to `localhost:3000/#` then redirects to `localhost:3000/login`.

**Case 2:** with history of Case 1

After successful login from `localhost:3000/login`, router redirects to `localhost:3000/#`.

After logout, router first redirects to `localhost:3000/#` then redirects to `localhost:3000/login`.

My question is why `localhost:3000/#` appeared in above cases and how can I get rid of them.

My routes setting is

```
export const LoginRoutes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/myapp/dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {   path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent
    }
];
```

and

```
export const ProtectedRoutes: RouterConfig = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/myapp',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    },
    {
        path: 'myapp',
        component: RouteDispatcherComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/myapp/dashboard',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            },
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                component: DashboardComponent
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In my login component, I use `this.router.navigate(['/myapp/dashboard']);` to navigate to my dashboard page.

And the `AuthGuard` is like

```
canActivate() {
    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
        return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    return false;
}
```

By the way, this happened in more than one browser (chrome, firefox, safari).

Answer (score 0):

I came back to answer my own question. It turns out that it's not an issue related to router setting but an issue in my html file.

I have

```
<a href="#" (click)="logoutClick($event)">
```

in my html file and have

```
logoutClick(event) {
    this.auth.logout();
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
}
```

in the corresponding ts file.

So, that's why it's first redirected to `localhost:3000/#` and then to `localhost:3000/login`. The `localhost:3000/#` is acutually not a valid route. The whole angular instance is reloaded and redirect to the login page by default.

To fix it, either change the html to

```
<a [routerLink]="['/login']" (click)="logoutClick($event)">
```

and remove `this.router.navigate(['login']);` from logoutClick(event)` method or simply change html to

```
<a (click)="logoutClick($event)">
```